# Scilab - Missing operator, comma or semicolon - error 276

Tags: syntax-error, scilab

I'm trying to read an ASCII data file in Scilab 5.4.1 and I get the following error
message:

```
x=read('g:\Work\WD\Debug\wd.txt',100,4,(5x,a2,3(5x,e12.4)))
                                      !--error 276 
Falta operador, coma o punto y coma.
(Missing operator, comma or semicolon.)
```

I've read the Scilab help about the 'read' command, and I've googled about this error
message, but I've not found anything useful. The error seems no to be in the ASCII data
file, because I can open it with:

```
wd=mopen('g:\Work\WD\Debug\wd.txt','r',1)
wd  =

1.
```

but when I try reading this file I get again the same error message:

```
x=read(1,100,4,(5x,a2,3(5x,e12.4)))
                 !--error 276 
Falta operador, coma o punto y coma.
```

I must say I'm new in Scilab, and surely I'm doing something wrong, but don't know
what. Help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Does it read the file while omitting the format argument?

```
x=read('g:\Work\WD\Debug\wd.txt',100,4)
```

I am suspecting it has something to do with your formatting string.

```
(5x,a2,3(5x,e12.4))
```

Maybe have a look [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Edit+descriptors) to learn more about Fortran format edit descriptors.